# get value from the button element that I click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have three button in html:

```
<button value="Rock" onclick="displayResult()">Rock</button>
<button value="Paper" onclick="displayResult()">Paper</button>
<button value="Scissors" onclick="displayResult()">Scissors</button>
```

In *displayResult()* function (wrriten once for 3), how can I get value from the button that I click? If I set ids for all 3 button, I have to write 3 display function to get value from a seperate button:

```
let displayResultForRock = () => {
  let value = document.getElementById('rock').value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code. you can update your `displayResult` function like this.

```js
function displayResult(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

```html
<button value="Rock" onclick="displayResult(event)">Rock</button>
<button value="Paper" onclick="displayResult(event)">Paper</button>
<button value="Scissors" onclick="displayResult(event)">Scissors</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just attach event listeners to the buttons, and then log the `textContent` of each.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
});

function handleClick() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button>Rock</button>
<button>Paper</button>
<button>Scissors</button>
```

Or use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation):

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('#buttons');

buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button>Rock</button>
  <button>Paper</button>
  <button>Scissors</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button")
btns.forEach(b => b.onclick = e => result.innerText = e.target.value)
```

```html
<button value="Rock">Rock</button>
<button value="Paper">Paper</button>
<button value="Scissors">Scissors</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just pass the value as parameter to the function like this:

```
<button value="Rock" onclick="displayResult("Rock")">Rock</button>
```